# How to enable/disable lock screen from the command line

Tags: command-line, scripts, lubuntu, xfce, lock-screen

I want to be able to quickly and easily enable and disable the lock screen.  Right now, I have to go to Menu > Preferences > Power Manager > Security then check or uncheck the check box marked "Lock screen when system is going for sleep", then in a terminal find the process id of `xfce4-power-manager`, then send a HUP signal to that PID, although this last part seems unreliable, as sometimes it doesn't take effect until the second resume.

How can I automate the GUI part?  When I run the Power Manager GUI, I see the process `xfce4-power-manager-settings` running, so presumably I would need the equivalent command line command to run.

I'm running LUbuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled <value>
```

Enable lockscreen -> value: true

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled true
```

Disable lockscreen:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this assumes that I'm running the GNOME screensaver, not the LXDE screensaver.